# "merge" rows/columns in Gridlayout in Android

Tags: android, grid-layout

I am new to Android, I am trying to using Gridlayout, but have a bit of trouble, I dont know how can i merge comlumns/rows in Gridlayout. In the code below, I try to use span, but in Description edittext, the Description column(column 0) keeps spanning and makes others column (column 1,2...) moving out of screen. How can I fix the problem ?

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:columnCount="6" android:rowCount="8" android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Goal"
        android:layout_columnSpan="6"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/goalNameLb" android:layout_row="1" android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/goalName" android:layout_row="1" android:layout_column="1"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="Goal Type"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/goalTypeLb" android:layout_row="2" android:layout_column="0"/>
<RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Short Term"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/shortTerm" android:layout_row="3" android:layout_column="0" android:checked="false"/>
<RadioButton
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Long Term"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/longTerm" android:layout_row="3" android:layout_column="2"
        android:checked="false"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
<EditText
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/goalName" android:layout_row="5" android:layout_column="0"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/deadlineLb"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Deadline"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Which device have you tested?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using fixed values for layout design.It may cause problem for the generic view.You can use table layout.For example visit the following link.
    1.[Link1](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/)  2.[Link2](http://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74&aaid=98)

Comment: i get it, but there's no solution for Gridlayout ?

Comment: @NhatTran Mostly grid layout is used for displaying image buttons and views.You are dealing with only components.Hence I suggest table layout for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout_columnSpan` to merge columns, and `layout_rowSpan` to merge rows. You can set the merge in each control.

In your case, for merge Description `TextView` into column 1 and column 2:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2" 
        />
```

You can find more information here: [GridLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams)

Answer (score -1):

I know it's an old question, but I have an alternative solution. 
You can use a LinearLayout block to contain multiple items. This LinearLayout will be 'seen' as 1 element by the GridLayout.